# can anyone help me to interface hardware using ethercat in ROS

Tags: ros, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can anyone help me to interface hardware using ethercat in ROS with step by step procedure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253291/can-anyone-help-me-to-interface-hardware-using-ethercat-in-ros/) by [ashok](https://answers.ros.org/users/28874/ashok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

" SOEM is an open source EtherCAT master library written in c" which is available @ https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociet... . After that try to go through the example codes in following link https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociet...

1. Download the repository SOEM-master and create a build directory in the path according to you ../../SOEM-master/ 2) Then again crate a test directory in side your build directory ../../SOEM-master/build/test/ 3) Now compile the package alone using cmake .. & make commands in the path ../../SOEM-master/ 4) Then find the executables generated in the path ../../SOEM-master/build/test/ 5) Connect your motor drive using Ethernet cable to your PC 6) Try to run the simple_test executable with sudo permissions as follows sudo ./simpple_test eth0 or eth1 7) Try to understand the response got from the ethercat slave drive like name, id , revision and cross check with the manufacturer data sheet 8) Now decide yourself in which mode you want to run the ethercat slaves for example cyclic synchronous torque mode you can get the example code in the following link https://gist.github.com/manuelvonthro... 9) Below are the best web links to extend the application code for your requirement http://www.elmomc.com/support/manuals... https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct...

---

Originally posted by [TraiBo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28181/traibo/) with karma: 146 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1